# Gnone-Wayland: Does launching a pkexec prompt from an X11 terminal (ex terminology in xwayland) result in a X11 pkexec prompt?

Tags: command-line, xorg, wayland, pkexec

A few months ago I've learned about some pretty big security holes in X11: such as vulnerability to getting your keystrokes sniffed by other X11 programs, programs being able to send keystrokes (and therefore commands) to each other, etc, etc.

So I've made steps to run my sessions in Gnome-Shell Wayland and use as much as possible applications that run natively under Wayland (seeing how the above mentioned vulnerabilities apply to running X native apps under XWayland too).

I have a terminal app that I really like called terminology. It only runs native X11, so I tend to do non-security sensitive tasks on it and never use sudo with it.

My question is as follows. If I run a pkexec command out of terminology, will the resulting pkexec prompt be a Wayland gui (seeing how the current session is a Wayland session) or will it be a X11 gui since the parent app that called it was running under X-Wayland?

Comment: In theory, all apps should run in wayland if possible. This is how I determine if an app is using wayland or xwayland- http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/how-to-determine-if-an-application-is-using-wayland-or-xwayland/

Comment: I haven't ever run gotten Wayland to run, but I'd think that XWayland or not, it should contact the session's authentication agent, which should be the GNOME Polkit agent, so if any prompts do come up, it will be from GNOME Shell.

Comment: @muru, yeah that makes sense.  so if the shell is running under wayland, the pkexec prompt will be a wayland gui.

Comment: @Panther thanks for the link. I've using xeyes to do something very similar but I am unable to use either my method or the trick in the link you gave me with pkexec since it freeze your ability to do anything until you enter your pw into the prompt.